# How to expand a MACRO into NSString without using any string concatenation at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, macros, nsstring, c-preprocessor

I defined a macro MYMACRO. **Note:** the value is not a valid NSString.

```
#define MYMACRO is
```

The macro is used **inside** the declaration of a NSString

```
@"This MYMACRO fun"
```

However, the preprocessor does not expand the macro. The preprocessed result is

```
@"This MYMACRO fun"
```

The best solution I found so far to get the macro to expand is:

```
#define MYMACRO @"is"
@"This "MYMACRO@" fun"
```

The macro expands as below which is a valid Objective-C syntax:

```
@"This "@"is"@" fun"
```

However, this requires 2 concatenation at runtime.

So my question is **how to insert a macro insto a NSString without using any string concatenation at runtime ?**

Ideally, I would like the runtime execute `@"This is fun"` rather than `@"This "@"is"@" fun"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fairly certain what you have is already concatenating at compile time, and not runtime.

Comment: You are correct. If you generate the assembly for code that does concatenation like this, you can see that it ends up as one .asciiz string.

Comment: I think it's also worth adding that even if the concatenation did happen at runtime, it's not worth bending over backwards to write some ugly macro just to save a few string operations. Write clear code first and then worry about performance. Personally I would be looking at using stringWithFormat to insert one NSString inside of another.

Comment: @AdamW: Do you mean the compiler optimizes @"This "@"is"@" fun" into @"This is fun" at compile time ?

I agree with you, I prefer to have simple source code instead of saving a few string operations. I am falling into premature optimization and we all know what it means: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil - D. Knuth"

Comment: @DavidAndreoletti: That's correct; it's part of the C language spec that consecutive constant string tokens are combined together **by the compiler** into a single string. This is true for both C-strings and Objective-C strings.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define MYMACRO @"is"
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This %@ fun",MYMACRO]
```